# Capture logging output using subprocess.check_output in Python

Tags: python, logging, subprocess, bots

I'm running a Telegram bot which is basically an interface to a Bayesian classifier that I made. I made a command to start a test on the remote server and the tester was originally using the `logging` module to print information about the test to stdout. When I tried to spawn a subprocess through `subprocess.check_output` I noticed that both stdout and stderr where empty byte strings. I worked around this by replacing the last `logging.info` call, the one that really matters, with a `print` function. What I'm guessing is that `logging` does not write on the same stdout that `subprocess.check_output` is expecting? Am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT**

As asked I'm adding a bit more context about what code I'm actually running. I don't know if this matters, but for the sake of completeness I'll add that the framework I'm using to run the bot is pyrogram.

The tester that gets called by the bot can be found [here](https://del.dog/lopucydylo.txt), while the code of the bot calling that script is [here](https://del.dog/onullistiw.txt)

Comment: Can you see the log messages if you run the application "as is" in a terminal?

Comment: Yeah, I do, and actually when subprocess.check_output runs I see the logs in the terminal but the module seems unable to see them

Comment: Can you add the relevant code to this problem? Both the `subprocess._check_output` setup as well as the code in regards to where the output is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm guessing is that logging does not write on the same stdout that subprocess.check_output is expecting?

`logging` doesn't write to stdout at all (by default); it writes to stderr.

You will need to either redirect your stderr to stdout by adding the `stderr` argument thus: `subprocess.check_output(..., stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)` or you will need to use one of the other subprocess functions such as `run` that gives access to stderr.

The docs do say:

> The recommended approach to invoking subprocesses is to use the run() function for all use cases it can handle

Comment: When you said you noticed stderr was an empty byte string, I'm not sure where you would have been looking as check_output returns just stdout. check_output has  stderr=None defaulted in its argument signature, so it discards stderr. The process to capture standard error using check_output is documented in the description of the function here https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it was just stdout, anyway I didn't knew that logging actually wrote to stderr, will try and see if this fixes the issue, thanks!